# is there a way in firebase to prevent writes in quick succession?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I've written a very simple polling script that saves votes to a Firebase database. To prevent multiple votes by the same user, I'm saving email to a separate object then checking for it before a new entry can be placed(this thing is for my own info and doesn't need to be high security).

So far it does seem to be preventing basic foul play, however I am getting many instances of multiple votes in quick succession (likely faster than the browser could reload). In the worst case there were 16 votes cast milliseconds apart.

is there a way to prevent these quick succession writes in Firebase or on the JavaScript side?

Firebase data:

```
{
  "votes" : {
    " obj1 " : {
      "-KHXPWtcxzXhs2ULBE1Q" : {
        "name" : " name1 ",
        "email" : "email1",
        "timestamp" : 1463013744297
      },
      "-KHXPWuyhTg6S3Qcw4e9" : {
        "name" : " name1 ",
        "email" : "email1",
        "timestamp" : 1463013744382
      }
    },
    "obj2" : {
      "-KHZ20CRiT5fs6H4Nhel" : {
        "name" : "name2",
        "email" : "email2",
        "timestamp" : 1463041135613
      }
    },
  },
  "email" : {
    "-KHXPWtHSNYWBmvXsmNx" : {
      "email" : "email1",
      "timestamp" : 1463013744292
    },
    "-KHXPWus4hSwi1t00Gq_" : {
      "email" : "email1",
      "timestamp" : 1463013744377
    },
    "-KHZ20CdfcsoGjvn98Q" : {
      "email" : "email2",
      "timestamp" : 1463041135606
    },
  }
}
```

The jQuery:

```
        var validateEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

        function castVote() {

          var ref = new Firebase('firebaseurl');

          $( ".notification.exists" ).hide();
          $( ".notification.valid" ).hide();

          var obj = $('#obj').val().toLowerCase();
          var email = $('#email').val().toLowerCase();

          var emailref = ref.child("email");

          if (validateEmail.test(email)){
            emailref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
                var exists = false;
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                    if(email === childSnapshot.val().email){
                        exists = true;     
                    }
                })

                if (exists){
                  $( ".notification.exists" ).show();
                }
                else{
                  write(obj,email,ref,emailref);
                }
            });
          }
          else{
            $( ".notification.valid" ).show();
          }
        }


        function write(obj,email,ref,emailref){

          var objref = ref.child("obj/" + obj);

          //save email
          emailref.push().set({
              email:email,
              "timestamp": Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            });

            //save vote
            objref.push().set({
              obj: obj,
              "email": email,
              "timestamp": Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            });

            //clear fields
            $('#obj').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
        }

      }
```

Comment: When calling `write` check a cooldown flag and `return` if true, set the cooldown flag, `setTimeout` to unflag it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should prevent this at Firebase end using security rules. A simple rule which prevents a user from re-voting could be -

Note that you would need to put this snippet at the right place in your security rule -

```
"votes" : {
   // keep .read/.write as applicable
   "$obj" : {
        "$user" : {
            // keep .read/.write as applicable
            // Don't allow write if the parent obj already contains this user entry
            ".validate" : "!data.parent().hasChild($user)"
        }
   }
}
```

This way, once you have inserted a user's vote into `votes` for a certain `obj`, another insertion will fail.

Comment: As I don't know your full JSON, I cannot help you with the exact security rule. If you could export JSON from Firebase and paste it here, it'd help.

Comment: the Json s above. The problem with this approach is that where you have $user under obj, I'm using push and therefore have unique keys, not verifiable users.

Comment: yeah, I don;t see why not

Comment: Unless you know who your users are (using Firebase Authentication), there is no way to ensure fairness. In most voting scenarios I see (and I see a lot of them), the developers want to limit it to "one vote per user". Storing it in the structure @HazardouS describes is the simplest way to ensure this requirement.

Comment: I had to replace all dots with underscores to use as an ID in firebase but this seems to be working well. Thanks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, yeah, we're just doing a bit of Market research. It's a simple popup that asks a single question. Once answered it uses cookies to prevent popping up again. There is no promised incentive so I doubt many would care to skew the results.